# Flutter padding issues on Android devices

Tags: android, flutter

I have the following widget in my Flutter app, which is pretty basic but for some reason, the padding is not working on some Android devices attached screenshot and code.

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Column(children: [
            Text(
              'register',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Availability results',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 6.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Showing results for',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '"${_availabilityRespose.query}"',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                  ),
                ),
```

It's bascially the padding in the list view

[image]

Comment: I think that's because like screen resolution or screen size issue. It's different from one device to another. Better use more dynamic approach like Flexible or Stack layout.

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Comment: can you add screenshot of device in which padding is not working

Answer (score 2):

instead of using static values you should use dynamic values with

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

which may solve your problem but it is not a good solution. try to use Expanded with flex

```
Expanded(flex: 1, child: yourChild())
```

[and you can test on device or emulator with different size and densities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Et4.png)